# Firefox won't show and hide my table properly. Only Shows header on button press not row

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, html-table

Firefox won't show and hide my table properly. Only Shows header on button press not row.

Basically what I'm wanting is for when the user clicks the button, the column header with the id "HideMe" and the rows of the same id are shown. This works perfectly in Chrome but not in Firefox

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Show and Hide Javascript won't work in Firefox</title>
    <style>
        #HideMe {
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('.ShowPassword').click(function () {
                $(HideMe).show();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID Number</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Middle Name</th>
            <th id="HideMe">Password</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2121</td>
            <td>Mike</td>
            <td>Daniel</td>
            <td id="HideMe">Password</td>
        </tr>
        <button class="ShowPassword">Show Password</button>
</body>
```

Comment: It is not a good practice to have DOM elements with the same id, you should use classes for that.

Comment: I tried that but still will not show hidden show in Firefox on button press

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in no way right

```
$(HideMe).show();
```

you may want to do something like:

```
$('#HideMe').show();
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/JS7tK/5/

I didn't notice at first but as bandi notes in his comment id should be unique.
So try to do something like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Show and Hide Javascript won't work in Firefox</title>
        <style>
            .HideMe {
                display:none;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                $('.ShowPassword').click(function () {
                    $('.HideMe').show();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID Number</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Middle Name</th>
                <th class="HideMe">Password</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2121</td>
                <td>Mike</td>
                <td>Daniel</td>
                <td class="HideMe">Password</td>
            </tr>
            <button class="ShowPassword">Show Password</button>
    </body>
<html>
```

Comment: Tried what you suggested still doesn't work in Firefox only shows header on button press.

Try:  jsfiddle.net/JS7tK 
in firefox and you will see the same

Comment: Tried your latest JFIDDLE and it still won't show the row hidden in Firefox on button press but it will within Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/JS7tK/

Comment: this is the last fiddle: jsfiddle.net/JS7tK/5 with class instead of id and it works fine on my firefox :-o

Answer (score 0):

I don't do jQuery, but as a rule you will undoubtedly be better off putting a span inside the  & hiding it rather than trying to hide the cell, because doing that would unbalance the table so no great surprise that some browsers do not allow it.

Comment: i Used span tags instead and still won't work in firefox
(Only shows column header on button press still) - Works fine in chrome)

http://jsfiddle.net/JcRCJ/1/

Comment: As @bandi said, you shouldn't have several elements with the same id, that will undoubtedly confuse the issue. Use classes or give them all the same name and cycle thru' them with a document.getElementsByName.